# Existence of non-locally constant function

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $K$ be a compact Hausdorff space without isolated points and let $x \in K$. Does there always exist a real-valued continuous function that is not locally constant near $x$?

If $K$ is metrizable this is easy, just take $y \mapsto d(x,y)$. However, in http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9505204 it is shown that there exist compact Hausdorff spaces such that the set of functions that are locally constant on a dense subset of $K$ is the whole of $C(K)$ (example: $\beta \mathbb{N} \setminus \mathbb{N}$). I'm not sure if that could yield a counterexample, though, as the functions are only locally constant on a dense subset of $K$ and not on the whole of $K$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A basic counterexample would be the extended long line $L^*$.  Recall that the *long line* is $L := \omega_1 \times [ 0 , 1 )$ given the topology of the lexicographic order.  $L^*$ is the one-point compactification of $L$, and may be visualised as $L^* := L \cup \{ \omega_1 = \langle  \omega_1 , 0 \rangle \}$ also given the topology of the lexicographic order.  This space is compact, Hausdorff, and has no isolated points.

Now, if $f : L^* \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, then for each $n > 0$ there is an $\alpha_n < \omega_1$ such that $| f(\xi , x ) - f ( \omega_1 ) | < \frac{1}{n}$ for all $\xi > \alpha_n$.  Letting $\alpha = \sup_n \alpha_n < \omega_1$, it follows that $f ( \xi , x ) = f ( \omega_1 )$ for all $\xi > \alpha$.

Comment: Nice counterexample. Another question - given a compact Hausdorff space without isolated points, can you always find a function that is not locally constant? In your example this is easy, but is there a general way of constructing such a function (or a counterexample)?

Comment: @Marten: I'm not certain if I understand your question above. As you mention in the question, there certainly are compact Hausdorff spaces with continuous functions which are not locally constant at a specific point. You can slightly improve your observation by weakening metrizable to first-countable. I cannot think of a weaker condition that would guarantee the existence of a continuous real-valued function which is not locally constant at a particular point. I'm not even certain what the case is for the Stone–Čech remainder $\beta \mathbb{N} \setminus \mathbb{N}$ of $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: I believe you interpreted my question correctly. I've asked it on Mathoverflow: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/156585/existence-of-non-locally-constant-functions